# assimp fail to find the obj. file

Tags: c++, assimp

I try to use  Assimp::Importer.ReadFile() to load my obj.file but it turns out that assimp fail to find the file correctly.

Here is a simple test

```
#include<string>
#include<assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   Assimp::Importer importer;
   string modelPath = "D:\\素材\\nanosuit\\nanosuit.obj";
   const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(modelPath, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs );
   if (!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) {
       cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP::" << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
   }
   else cout << scene;
```

and the output is following text

```
ERROR::ASSIMP::Unable to open file "D:\素材\nanosuit\nanosuit.obj".
```

I haved tried to load different obj.file and it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the unicode name. You need to use a workaround to fix this. Use the Wi32-API-Call

```
SetCurrentDirectory(L"D:\\素材\\nanosuit\\");
```

to open the folder and import the asset afterwards:

```
const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(L"nanosuit.obj", aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs );
```

There is a design error in the Asset-Importer-Lib. The imported name will be used to name the asset and the asset-name is using ASCII. So unicode names will interpreted as ASCII-names and this will cause your error.